# Adding captions and "cont." to framed quotations broken across multiple pages

Tags: captions, page-breaking, framed

I have to include transcriptions of interviews I had conducted in my thesis, and the institute to which I'll be submitting said thesis is imposing some limitations. The rules are:

- Excerpts should be framed.
- When the text spans multiple pages, each portion should be separately framed.
- Segments of the same dialogue should have the same caption and also the phrase "cont." after each segment, except of course the last.

I tried the `mframed` package, but it did not draw the lower/upper boundaries of the frames, so I went with the `framed` package which did the trick. I also chose the `dialogue` environment over `quote` and `quotation`.

I still don't know how to

- insert a caption, since this is not a float and making it a float prevents page breaks
- apply the same caption, and hence the same dialogue number to each part
- have LaTeX write "cont." after each part

Below is the like to an image of the minimal working example I wrote. I added the "cont." by image editing, to show how it has to look like (without the captions).

[image]

The code used to produce the output above is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{framed}
\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{The Researcher} If you were a teacher, how would you teach physics?
    A few seconds of silence
    \speak{The Researcher} Have you ever thought, ugh this is boring, I wish it were more like this…
    \speak{Student 1} It would probably be more experiment-oriented. I would conduct more experiments.
    \speak{Student 2} I would just write on the board like the usual.
    \speak{Student 1} Because when it is visual… I would choose to teach using experiments because since experiments are visual they are better able to maintain students’ attention.
    \speak{Student 3} I would probably use analogies, you know like with electromagnetic waves. Or mechanics perhaps.  I don’t know which type of wave sound waves are at the present, like those that require a medium or those that do not, I would say something like, I would tell them  for instance to consider sound, is sound mechanical?
    \speak{Student 2} Right.
    \speak{Student 3} ????? I would get them to remember by doing that, like when they think of sound , it requires a medium for propogation, and thus they would understand the properties of mechanical waves. I would do such things.
    \speak{Student 2} I would simply teach by writing on the board, this is the way I learn. I do not like to use visual materials that much.
    \speak{Student 4} I would write the summary on the board, and go on that when teaching.
    \speak{Student 5} Actually it is good to write…
    \speak{Student 2} I would give pointers; which topics produce more questions,  how to solve them…
    \speak{Student 5} Our elementary school teacher would give us two weeks to copy a 30-40 page material to paper, since it is easier to remember when you write it. It helped better commit that subject to memory since we also covered the same material in class, but it was boring since you listen to the same things that you wrote down, it was not fun. 
    \speak{The Researcher} Was copying it to your notebook enough to help you understand it fully that you got bored in class?
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
\end{dialogue}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How shoul this caption be? Just some text or do you need a label and a counter as in "Excerpt 1: this is the caption text"; where should this caption appear in the different parts of a split frame?

Comment: I was going to mention that, but I forgot, I do need a label and a counter, the caption should appear at the bottom of the frames, as with figures (or at the top, as with tables, but the captions should be either at the top or the bottom). "Excerpt 3.1: Dumb people talking" where 3 is the chapter counter and 1 is the excerpt counter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package, here's now a complete solution; the `myexcerpt` environment has two mandatory arguments: the first one for the caption, and the second one, for a label for eventual cross-references (the example illustrates this). All requirements are satisfied:

- Text is framed: If page breaks occur, every part of the aplit frame is completely framed.
- For split frames, all parts, except the last one, receive the "cont." text at the bottom (provision was made as not to exceed the bottom margin).
- Frames can receive a caption with a label and automating numbering; the caption text appears at the top of the frame; for split frames, the caption appears at the top of each split part.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{exc}
\counterwithin{exc}{chapter}

\newlength\CapHt
\newlength\CapDp

\newcommand\excerptname{Excerpt}
\newcommand\exccaptionfont{\normalfont\small}

\newtcolorbox{myexcerpt}[2]{%
breakable,
enhanced,
freelance,
frame code={
  \draw[line width=1pt] 
    ([yshift=1pt]interior.north west-|frame.north west) --
    ([yshift=1pt]interior.north east-|frame.north east) --
    (frame.south east) -- 
    (frame.south west) -- 
    cycle;
  },
colback=white,
top=4mm,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
coltitle=black,
fonttitle=\normalfont\small,
step and label={exc}{#2},
title={\noindent\justifying\excerptname~\theexc: #1},
title after break={\noindent\justifying\excerptname~\theexc: #1},
overlay middle={%
  \node[
    inner xsep=0pt,
    anchor=north east,
    font=\footnotesize\color{red}]
  at (frame.south east) {cont.};
  },
overlay first={%
  \node[
    inner xsep=0pt,
    anchor=north east,
    font=\footnotesize\color{red}]
  at (frame.south east) {cont.};
  },
enlarge top by=\topskip,
enlarge top at break by=0pt,
enlarge bottom at break by=\baselineskip,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
Some cross-references to the dialogues~\ref{exc:long} and~\ref{exc:short}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{myexcerpt}{some text that will be used for the caption of this long dialogue and we add some additional test text}{exc:long}
\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{The Researcher} If you were a teacher, how would you teach physics?
    A few seconds of silence
    \speak{The Researcher} Have you ever thought, ugh this is boring, I wish it were more like this…
    \speak{Student 1} It would probably be more experiment-oriented. I would conduct more experiments.
    \speak{Student 2} I would just write on the board like the usual.
    \speak{Student 1} Because when it is visual… I would choose to teach using experiments because since experiments are visual they are better able to maintain students’ attention.
    \speak{Student 3} I would probably use analogies, you know like with electromagnetic waves. Or mechanics perhaps.  I don’t know which type of wave sound waves are at the present, like those that require a medium or those that do not, I would say something like, I would tell them  for instance to consider sound, is sound mechanical?
    \speak{Student 2} Right.
    \speak{Student 3} ????? I would get them to remember by doing that, like when they think of sound , it requires a medium for propogation, and thus they would understand the properties of mechanical waves. I would do such things.
    \speak{Student 2} I would simply teach by writing on the board, this is the way I learn. I do not like to use visual materials that much.
    \speak{Student 4} I would write the summary on the board, and go on that when teaching.
    \speak{Student 5} Actually it is good to write…
    \speak{Student 2} I would give pointers; which topics produce more questions,  how to solve them…
    \speak{Student 5} Our elementary school teacher would give us two weeks to copy a 30-40 page material to paper, since it is easier to remember when you write it. It helped better commit that subject to memory since we also covered the same material in class, but it was boring since you listen to the same things that you wrote down, it was not fun. 
    \speak{The Researcher} Was copying it to your notebook enough to help you understand it fully that you got bored in class?
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
\end{dialogue}
\end{myexcerpt}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{myexcerpt}{this is the description of the second dialogue}{exc:short}
\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{The Researcher} If you were a teacher, how would you teach physics?
    A few seconds of silence
    \speak{The Researcher} Have you ever thought, ugh this is boring, I wish it were more like this…
    \speak{Student 1} It would probably be more experiment-oriented. I would conduct more experiments.
    \speak{Student 2} I would just write on the board like the usual.
    \speak{Student 1} Because when it is visual… I would choose to teach using experiments because since experiments are visual they are better able to maintain students’ attention.
\end{dialogue}
\end{myexcerpt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code was the first proposed solution. It's still not perfect since the caption appears inside the frame. The modifications required are not so difficult, but I will leave it in its present form (for the moment) since I have already dedicated enough time to this question.

You can use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package; its `firstextra` and `middleextra` keys allow you to add the "cont." text for the required frames at the desired position; I also defined a new mdf key allowing you to pass a caption; the environment automatically adds the label `Excerpt <number>:` before the actual caption text; `<number>` is a string of the form `<chapter number>.<excerpt number>`; the `exc` counter for `<excerpt number>` resets at every new chapter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcounter{exc}
\counterwithin{exc}{chapter}

\newcommand\excerptname{Excerpt}

\makeatletter
% mdf key for the caption
\def\mdf@@caption{}
\define@key{mdf}{caption}{\def\mdf@@caption{#1}}

\newmdenv[
settings={\refstepcounter{exc}},
everyline=true,
linewidth=1pt,
repeatframetitle=true,
frametitle={%
  \ifdefempty{\mdf@@caption}{}  
    {\excerptname~\theexc:~\mdf@@caption}%
  },
frametitlefont=\normalfont\small,
firstextra={%
  \node[fill=white,anchor=east,inner xsep=0pt,yshift=-10pt,
    font=\footnotesize\color{red}] 
    at (P|-O) {cont.};%
  },
middleextra={%
  \node[fill=white,anchor=east,inner xsep=0pt,yshift=-10pt,
    font=\footnotesize\color{red}] 
    at (P|-O) {cont.};%
  },
]{myexcerpt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[2-5]
\begin{myexcerpt}[caption={this is the description of this dialogue; it is a little long just  for this example so that it spans two lines}]
\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{The Researcher} If you were a teacher, how would you teach physics?
    A few seconds of silence
    \speak{The Researcher} Have you ever thought, ugh this is boring, I wish it were more like this…
    \speak{Student 1} It would probably be more experiment-oriented. I would conduct more experiments.
    \speak{Student 2} I would just write on the board like the usual.
    \speak{Student 1} Because when it is visual… I would choose to teach using experiments because since experiments are visual they are better able to maintain students’ attention.
    \speak{Student 3} I would probably use analogies, you know like with electromagnetic waves. Or mechanics perhaps.  I don’t know which type of wave sound waves are at the present, like those that require a medium or those that do not, I would say something like, I would tell them  for instance to consider sound, is sound mechanical?
    \speak{Student 2} Right.
    \speak{Student 3} ????? I would get them to remember by doing that, like when they think of sound , it requires a medium for propogation, and thus they would understand the properties of mechanical waves. I would do such things.
    \speak{Student 2} I would simply teach by writing on the board, this is the way I learn. I do not like to use visual materials that much.
    \speak{Student 4} I would write the summary on the board, and go on that when teaching.
    \speak{Student 5} Actually it is good to write…
    \speak{Student 2} I would give pointers; which topics produce more questions,  how to solve them…
    \speak{Student 5} Our elementary school teacher would give us two weeks to copy a 30-40 page material to paper, since it is easier to remember when you write it. It helped better commit that subject to memory since we also covered the same material in class, but it was boring since you listen to the same things that you wrote down, it was not fun. 
    \speak{The Researcher} Was copying it to your notebook enough to help you understand it fully that you got bored in class?
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
    \speak{Student 5} You do understand it.
    \speak{Student 2} If visual materials, slides or experiments are to be used we have to study daily for us to remember. Yet I forget since I do not study daily.
\end{dialogue}
\end{myexcerpt}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{myexcerpt}[caption={this is the description of the second dialogue}]
\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{The Researcher} If you were a teacher, how would you teach physics?
    A few seconds of silence
    \speak{The Researcher} Have you ever thought, ugh this is boring, I wish it were more like this…
    \speak{Student 1} It would probably be more experiment-oriented. I would conduct more experiments.
    \speak{Student 2} I would just write on the board like the usual.
    \speak{Student 1} Because when it is visual… I would choose to teach using experiments because since experiments are visual they are better able to maintain students’ attention.
\end{dialogue}
\end{myexcerpt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, now I just have to figure out how to append captions to all segments of the page-broken frame. Also, mdframed is accounting for the extra line created by the "cont." that follows to make sure it obeys the margin, right?

Comment: @cimicimbo not at the moment (since you didn't mention this), but this can be fixed. The captions part might require a little more work, since their height is variable. In a few hours (I have to leave now) I can propose a possible solution for this. Just to be sure: should the captions appear inside the frame? and should they appear on every part of a split frame or just in the first/last?

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, thanks for you help, they should appear outside the frames, and yes on every part of a split frame. So if the frame were split into three, all three would feature "Excerpt x.y: People talking about stuff" at the top|bottom of the frame.

Comment: @cimicimbo I updated my answer with a now complete solution using the `tcolorbox` package (make sure to have the latest version of the package installed in your system).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. Your last answer is perfect. Before I saw that, I was trying to make the frametitleaboveskip negative to move the title out of the box, it did not work well. You have inspired me to help others out on this site, but I fear my lack of experience may be detrimental instead of helpful =|

Comment: @cimicimbo You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. It's great that you are considering to offer help here; I'm sure you can help others. If lack of experience worries you, hang around for a while, reading questions and answers, and you'll soon get a vast amount of experience :-).